# What is the use of the variable "MAP_WIDTH = 64" in the following code for rendering sprite sheets

Tags: java, arrays, sprite, game-engine, sprite-sheet

i'm wondering what "MAP_WIDTH = 64" does in the following code. It is taken from an episode in a series of videos on Java 2d game engine design and i have linked the video in question.

The sprite sheet being used is a 256 x 256 .png with grids/tiles/sprites(?) of 8 x 8. The sprite sheet is only using 4 colours and they are setting each of these 4 colours to something else within the code. The following code is in the first minute of the video linked at the bottom. (some variables relating to the rendering omitted)

I cant for the life of me figure out what is going on. Where does the 64 come from? The only thing i can see is that there are 64 pixels in a 8 x 8 grid, but then why multiply this by 64 again? It cant be the pixels per row/column as there is 256 of these and cant be the number of tiles as there are 32 of these per row/column.

I can kind of see why the int colours[] is 4 times bigger than the tiles array as each pixel can be one of 4 values but im having a hard time grasping this.

```
public class Screen{
   public static final int MAP_WIDTH = 64;
   public static final int MAP_WIDTH = MAP_WIDTH - 1;

   public int[] tiles = new int[MAP_WIDTH * MAP_WIDTH]
   public int[] colours = new int[MAP_WIDTH * MAP_WIDTH * 4]


   public Screen(){
       for(int i =0; i<MAP_WIDTH * MAP_WIDTH; i++){
           colours[i*4 +0] = 0xff00ff;
           colours[i*4 +1] = 0x00ffff;
           colours[i*4 +2] = 0xffff00;
           colours[i*4 +3] = 0xffffff;
       }
   }
}
```

[YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FMgQNDNMJc)

Comment: That is fairly confusing... At first glance I'd think that the reason the colors size is 4 times larger is for 4 color channels (red/green/blue/alpha), but then it really shouldn't be an int (only 256 possible values for each channel, int gives way more than that as possible values).

Comment: `public static final int MAP_WIDTH = 64; public static final int MAP_WIDTH = MAP_WIDTH - 1;` Will not compile. Fields can't have the same name.